# finding the force needed based on distances between objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, physics, unityscript

Trying to programatically set the force based on the distance of the selected object, and another static object.

To understand this better I am making a golf game, I have forced being applied to ball already done but I am manually setting the force at this point. Right now I am trying to build some pseudo-code for how I can accomplish this. I do not have a lot of experience with physics so anything will help here. But basically I have a golfer who selects an area that he would like to hit it to. So once selected, I will grab the location of the selection, obviously find the difference via (selected.transform.position - golfer.transform.position) but now I am a little stuck on what to do next. How can I find the force needed to get to the selected location?

here's some current code in case it helps

```
var target : Transform;
var speed : float;
var force : float;
var angle = 50;
var i = 1;

function FixedUpdate()
{
    if (target == null)
        target = GameObject.FindWithTag("Hole").transform;
}

function Hit()
{
    var torque = Vector3(Input.GetAxis("Vertical"), 0, -Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
    var targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation (target.position-transform.position,Vector3.forward);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation,targetRotation,8);

    transform.eulerAngles.x = -angle;
        rigidbody.AddTorque(torque.normalized*speed);
    rigidbody.AddForceAtPosition (transform.forward * speed * force,target.position, ForceMode.VelocityChange );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a few things.

- Angle of Force `theta`
- Mass of object `m`

On the x-axis:

- Acceleration `a`
- Initial velocity `vi`
- Final velocity `vf`
- Distance `d`
- Time to travel `t`

On the y-axis:

- Acceleration `a = gravity`
- Initial velocity `vi_y`
- Final velocity `vf_y`
- Height traveled `h`

Then use the equations for Kinematics and `F=ma` to find the force.

Your goal is to combine what you know, mass of object, distance, etc. and apply the equations of kinematics to find the acceleration needed on the x-axis. Then you will plug in that acceleration and the mass to `F=ma` to find the Force.

Comment: ok and assuming i have all of this information, is there a formula you know off hand? i tried to google some stuff but only came up with (force = m x a) which doesnt help me at all.